# Daemon process which accepts arguments and returns results

Tags: python

This is the scenario.

Run a python script in background.
Call this script using perl with arguments and returns a result to stdout.

How do I write this python script ?

Basically the question is how do I pass arguments to a running program ?  Is this possible (via threads/subprocess/etc/., ) ? else how do I approach this problem ?

Comment: Can you give more details on why do you need a program running in background? Do you need a daemon? Or maybe executing a program in separate thread and then blocking it until the program ends is enough?

Comment: Yes, I could write a thread to block.  But how do I pass arguments and get return values ?
@Corey - Yes, how do I design a (simple) server ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good usage for something like [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). You can invoke methods of the python script which runs as a server. No need to resort to capturing stdout, you can just have the python script return a string to the caller.